# Index match and sum the value based on the occurrence on one column and adding the values from the respective adjacent column

Tags: excel

For example, The C column 'Person' in the screenshot below, which will be randomly sorted. The formula on the right, where I need the SUM has to first match the keyword 'A' with C3:C14 (as in E7) and then add the scores from the B (B3:B14) column at all the occurrences in the adjacent C(C3:C14) column if the match with keyword at E7 is found.

I tried using Sum Index match to do the summation of all the values as you can see in the example below, but only finds the first one. I manually typed the output in G7 which is the desired output.

Formula used in H7 is this, which doesn't work-

```
SUM(INDEX(B3:B14,MATCH(E7,C3:C14,0)),0)
```

[image: Example]

Comment: You need the SUMIF formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In F7 use

```
=Sumifs(B:B,C:C,E7)
```

Copy down.

For a more dynamic approach consider using a pivot table. Then you don't have to manually create the list of people in column E.

Or use the new Dynamic array functions to create a unique list. In E7 use

```
=UNIQUE(C3:C14)
```

in F7 use

```
=SUMIFS(B3:B14,C3:C14,E7#)
```

No need to copy down. The formulas will "spill" automatically. This approach is only available in Excel with an Office 354 license.

[image]

Comment: That is awesome. I sincerely appreciate your help @teylyn. Thank you very much!